# How do I make the cursor color the inverse of the character color?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, vi

If I type `{}` inside the gnome terminal and move the cursor over `{` or `}` the color of the cursor changes to the color of the `{` character, so I can't see the `{` character.

How do I make the cursor color the inverse of the character color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of `gnome-terminal`. Unless you explicitly set a `Profile Preferences` -> `Colors` -> `Cursor color`, and assuming that you use the default `Profile Preferences` -> `General` -> `Cursor shape`: `Block`, the cell under the cursor is inverted (that is, its foreground and background colors are swapped).

What I believe might happen to you is what's discussed at https://github.com/tomasr/molokai/pull/44. I think you might be using a color scheme that highlights matching `{` and `}` characters, probably by inverting both of them. That is, in this case probably your `vim` explicitly inverts the character cell under the cursor, and `gnome-terminal` inverts it again... or something very similar to this.

I recommend that you (at least temporarily) switch to `I-Beam` or `Underline` cursor shape to verify this theory. If we're indeed on the right track, you should ask the maintainers of your `vim` color scheme to fix it, or probably even ask `vim` to make it possible for color schemes to highlight (invert) the counterpart brace only, not the one under the cursor.

Comment: If I for example `vi test` there is no problem with seeing `}` or `{`.  However if I `vi test.js` then the block cursor has the same color as the `}`